# fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found in flutter IOS Build

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           14.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/d7/k5tgg8zx1fb1hlrnhzbg4l_40000gn/T/flutter_tools.FBHN8u/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirQbWTC1/temporary_xcresult_bundle

```
In file included from /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/3.3.3/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_ios-6.0.17/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:7:
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/3.3.3/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_ios-6.0.17/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
In file included from /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/3.3.3/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_ios-2.1.1/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.m:5:
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/3.3.3/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_ios-2.1.1/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Building targets in dependency order
warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Result bundle written to path:
    /var/folders/d7/k5tgg8zx1fb1hlrnhzbg4l_40000gn/T/flutter_tools.FBHN8u/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirQbWTC1/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/3.3.3/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_ios-6.0.17/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:4:8

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/3.3.3/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_ios-2.1.1/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:4:8

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.

right now and after downgrading cocopods to 1.10.0 and platform :ios, '13.0' the build works but the runner stopped when launching the app in the emulator

this is the

Running pod install... Running Xcode build... Xcode build done. 307,7s Exception: Unable to launch com.xxxxxxx.xxx on D94FEC60-1F58-427F-8C7D-2E8C216362C5: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally: An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1): The request to open "com.xxxxxxxxxx.xxx" failed. The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace). Underlying error (domain=FBProcessExit, code=128): The operation couldn’t be completed. The process exited. The process exited. Command: xcrun simctl launch D94FEC60-1F58-427F-8C7D-2E8C216362C5 com.xxxxxxx.xxxx --enable-dart-profiling --enable-checked-mode --verify-entry-points --start-paused --observatory-port=0 Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.

Comment: Thats the package itself try to get the new updated for shared pref also try to update the pod file

Comment: I did it, but it still doesn't work, I also deleted the rm -rf .pub-cache/hosted
 to flutter but nothing to do

Comment: Try to trace all of your packages which is indicate on the error given i think this is the package you put on the project try to update those

Comment: I followed your advice and updated all dependencies on the latest version but nothing to do sharedpreferences and the others remain in the same state I do not understand where this error comes from, for almost a year now I can't find this solution so I can't deploy my application on IOS because of this

Comment: have you tried deleting the podfile.lock then on the terminal pod install or pod update?

Comment: yes i have try it, it still not working

Comment: As i tried also upgrading my xcode to latest and run to iphone14 same result as yours probably these packages is not update labeling with the new swift recommended so i think try to downgrade xcode if you are releasing to appstore if not you can wait for the packages to be update the swift code

Comment: Have you also put an issue on this on the package on its own github repo?

Comment: Same issue here for Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:4:8 in url_launcher plugin

Comment: @ArbiterChil no I didn't put the problem on the repository, I think I'll try your approach first and downgrade the version of xcode and swift to try

Comment: @LoubayiPrinceThierry how did you solved this?

Comment: This issue is still ongoing, I can't find a solution.